# Error after upgrading Xcode Expected declaration

Tags: xcode, swift

```
@IBAction func newPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
if isCameraAvailable() && doesCameraSupportTakingPhotos(){
imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.delegate = self
presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
else {               
print("Camera is not available")
}
```

The error occurs in place of **else {** -expected Declaration
- Help me please!

Comment: If you *indent* your code properly then the error should become apparent immediately...

Comment: @MartinR agree once again...:)

Comment: Agree @MartinR. If you indent your code Mihail, then you will automatically come to know about the reason of error(extra closing bracket).

Answer (score 1):

Move One `}` before `else` to the end of `If else` statement

```
@IBAction func newPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isCameraAvailable() && doesCameraSupportTakingPhotos(){
               imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
               imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
               imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
               imagePicker.delegate = self
               presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {               
          print("Camera is not available")
    }
}
```

Comment: Then asks to put";" before else. P. S This was one of the first things that I attempted to correct the error..